getting cameras list on firefox with the camera_web flutter plugin causes an error
I'm trying to test basic camera implementation in my flutter app, in general in IOS and Android the app works great, I can record videos and even see a preview of the recorded videos.
in chrome I can record a video and watch it but I can't get the duration because of a webm chrome bug.
in Firefox when I just try to get the cameras list using:
cameras = await availableCameras();

get the javascript error:
TypeError: null: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'JSArray<Object?>'

I can't really show you any more code... cause literally that's it
in my initState() of my page I have a function initializeCamera()
and initialize camera is doing this:
  Future<void> initializeCamera() async {
    // Indicate that the camera is being initialized
    isCameraInitialized = false;
    setState(() {});

    try {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      debugPrint('Cameras found: $cameras');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error retrieving cameras: $e');
      return;
    }

I'm using flutter 3.27.0 with camera 0.11.0+2 and camera_web 0.3.5.
any ideas regarding this issue would be  greatly appreciated.
